# Should we add the tag CC-2014?

Tags: discussion

Since the new update of CC per the release I was curious if we should add [cc-2014](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc-2014) or [creative-cloud-2014](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-cloud-2014) to co exist with our tag structure..

We currently have for Adobe:

[cs3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs3)
[cs4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs4)
[cs5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs5)
[cs6](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cs6)
[creative-cloud](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-cloud)

Comment: I didn't even realize we had those. I'd scrap them all.

Comment: Thats a bad idea..  Because certain features are only allowed for certain software versions which is why I always edit the question.  That is also why you see some answers that say this can be done with THIS version and THIS version allowed this feature in its place.

Answer (score 1):

As a creative cloud user, I had no idea there was any new release. I was under the impression it just gets constant updates rather than new versions.

I agree that the other tags should be kept for organisation purposes, but I think the original creative cloud tag already covers any new edition - *for now*.

In addition to this, we didn't get many CC-2013-specific questions anyway, *and* I don't think it's even possible to download an old version of creative cloud. Once you sign up, you get whatever is the latest version released.

Comment: Nice to see you're still lurking around! When you update CC it didn't go over the old software. Now I've got Photoshop CC (64-bit) and Photoshop CC 2014 as an example.

Comment: I'd only create a new tag if there are significant changes to tools, otherwise and since subscription means latest CC I don't think it's necessary.